# How to solve StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I have this nextInt method that is giving me a stackoverflow error:

```
public int nextInt(int a){
        int n = rand.nextInt(a);
        return n;
    }
```

And is called by this line of code:

```
int index = rnd.nextInt(Words.size());
```

I understand why it's giving the error but I don't know how to fix it. I have a similar method in a different program that doesn't give me the error:

```
public int nextInt(int l, int h){
    int n = rand.nextInt(h - l + 1) + l;
    return n;
}
```

Which is being called by this line of code:

```
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10,20)); //prints random num between 10 and 20 inclusive
```

Any helpful pointers would be great!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include where these methods are declared and how they are called? Otherwise it's a bit hard to tell why you'd get an error.

Comment: What is `rand` in your question ? Please add more information.

Comment: I'll edit it to show where they are declared. `rand` will make the value that is passed random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to define the random object on that scope also or if you are defining random object else  then declare it global

you need to do like htis

```
public int nextInt(int a){

 // create random object
  Random rand = new Random();

 // check next int value
  int n = rand.nextInt(a);
  return n;
}
```

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes before it will let me.

Comment: @SeanLynch glad to help you and contribute to this comminity happy codding

Answer (score 0):

According to me recursion is not happening(infact, it seems to be the case of **method overloading**) in the below scenario:

```
public int nextInt(int l, int h){
    int n = rand.nextInt(h - l + 1) + l;
    return n;
}
```

because the `nextInt` method has two parameters while at `int n = rand.nextInt(h - l + 1) + l;` you are invoking `nextInt` with one parameter only.

Whereas in first scenario, `nextInt` method has only one parameter and within this method , you are doing recursive calls to the same `nextInt` method with single parameter.